# Замена обратных подстрок в строке

Tags: python, строки

Как можно, например, в строке `and ggg ge or asd < jfd >=` заменить подстроки согласно словарю:

```py
{">": "<=", ">=": "<", "<": ">=", "<=": ">", "or": "and", "and": "or"}
```

С применением `replace` и использованием цикла оно сначала меняет `or` в строке на `and`, а затем обратно на "or"

При использовании `translate` можно задать только набор символов на замену, а подстроки нельзя..

Возможно ли вообще как-то выполнить такую задачу..?

Comment: а какой язык то

Comment: во первых, добро пожаловать на ruSO. Было бы здорово, если бы к вопросу вы приложили язык программирования, на котором вы хотели бы видеть реализацию решения данной проблемы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [re.sub - поменять подстроки местами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1469075/re-sub-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обновленное решение на регулярных выражениях с учетом того, на что обратили внимание в комментариях:

- неправильно заменяло `>=`, т.к. реагирует на первый символ `>`;
- в строке вида `candle and biggle > 0` реагировало на `and` в слове `candle`.

На самом деле не самое оптимальное решение с точки зрения работы с входным словарем, здесь я его разбил на две части.

Цель всего действа сформировать регулярку: `>=|<=|>|<|\bor|\band`. Где `\b` это указатель на границу слова для регулярного выражения. Ну а дальше попросту ее применить с заменой.

```
import re

operator_subs = {
    ">=": "<",
    "<=": ">",
    ">": "<=",
    "<": ">="
}

word_subs = {
    "or": "and",
    "and": "or"
}

source_etalon_strings = {
    "and ggg ge or asd < jfd >=":
    "or ggg ge and asd >= jfd <",

    "candle and biggle > 0":
    "candle or biggle <= 0",

    "x < y and z > 10":
    "x >= y or z <= 10",

    "a >= b or c <= d":
    "a < b and c > d",

    "e and f or g < h > i":
    "e or f and g >= h <= i"
}


def replace(string):
    # строим регулярное выражение
    pattern_string = ("|".join(re.escape(key) for key in operator_subs.keys())
                      + "|" + "|".join(r"\b" + key for key in word_subs.keys()))
    pattern = re.compile(pattern_string)

    # для замены объединяем все словари подстановок в один
    total_subs = {}
    total_subs.update(operator_subs)
    total_subs.update(word_subs)

    # с помощью регулярного выражения находим совпадения и заменяем
    result = pattern.sub(lambda x: total_subs[x.group()], string)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for src_string, etalon_string in source_etalon_strings.items():
        res_string = replace(src_string)

        print(f"Source: {src_string}")
        print(f"Etalon: {etalon_string}")
        print(f"Result: {res_string}")
        print(res_string == etalon_string)
        print("****************************")
```

Comment: Плюсик за `re.escape`. Все про него забывают, вы помните.

Comment: Крутое решение! Подскажите, а не смогли бы вы в двух словах описать, что именно здесь происходит..?))

Comment: и ещё: можно как-то сделать, чтобы оно искало только отдельные слова, а то оно текст "candle and biggle > 0" поменяло на "corle or biggle <= 0" ))))

Comment: `re.escape(key)` -> `re.escape(' ' + key + ' ')` и `pattern.sub(..., string)` -> `pattern.sub(..., ' ' + string + ' ')`.

Comment: Обновил исходное сообщение с учетом ваших предложений.
По поводу того как работает, тут нужно погрузиться в прекрасный мир регулярных выражений, тут лучше уже самому почитать и поизучать. Есть куча онлайн площадок, которые позволяют на ходу строить и отлаживать регулярки, например: https://regex101.com/

Comment: `android`, `original`. Границы слов надо с обоих сторон делать.

Answer (score 3):

Решение без регулярки. Не такое красивое и эффективное, как с регуляркой, но рабочее (для альтернативы)

```
t = "and ggg ge or asd < jfd >="
d = {">": "<=", ">=": "<", "<": ">=", "<=": ">", "or": "and", "and": "or"}
l = sorted(d.keys(), key=len, reverse=True)  # упорядочиваем поисковые образцы от длинных к коротким

out, i = '', 0  # буфер для результата и указатель
while i < len(t):  # пока строка не закончилась,
    for el in l:  # подбираем образец с начала очередного среза
        if t[i:].startswith(el):  # если образец подошел,
            out += d[el]  # помещаем соотв. значение из словаря в буфер
            i += len(el)  # и прибавляем к указателю длину замененного фрагмента, чтобы повторно его не обработать
            break  # переходим к следующему срезу
    else:
        out += t[i]  # если образец не найден, то в буфер помещаем очередной символ
        i += 1  # и указатель сдвигаем на 1 вправо
print(out)
```

Вывод:

```
or ggg ge and asd >= jfd <
```

Comment: Да, тоже хорошо получилось, на моих тестах все прошло. Поставил плюсик)

Comment: Ещё можно [trie](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) добавить. Для пущей эффективности.